# Spring/Hibernate Select Count(*) Query Customizing?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

Please help me,

Here's my DAO that gave me correct number of rows but I want to add some conditions.

```
@Override
public int getAllRows(SearchForm searchForm) {
    logger.info("SearchForm Detail :: " + searchForm);
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query = (Query) session.createQuery(" select count(*) from EmployeeVO");
    int rows = ((Number) query.uniqueResult()).intValue();
    logger.info("Number of Rows :: " + rows);
    return rows;
}
```

this is my MySQL Query :

SELECT 
first_name

FROM 
employees

WHERE 
first_name LIKE '%ab%'

AND 
salary > 0 and salary < 100000;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Query query = (Query) session.createQuery("SELECT first_name FROM employees WHERE first_name LIKE ? AND salary > ? and salary < ?");
query.setParameter(0, '%ab%');
query.setParameter(1, 0);
query.setParameter(2, 100000);
```

You can also use named parameters also as below:

```
Query query = (Query) session.createQuery("SELECT first_name FROM employees WHERE first_name LIKE :first_name AND salary > :min_salary and salary < :max_salary");
query.setParameter(first_name, '%ab%');
query.setParameter(min_salary, 0);
query.setParameter(max_salary, 100000);
```

Another alternate is to use the Hibernate Criteria API:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("first_name", "%ab%"));
criteria.add(Restrictions.lt("salary ", 0));
criteria.add(Restrictions.gt("salary ", 100000));
List list = criteria.list();
```

Comment: Moreover, You can tweak it in more loosely coupled way:                      
USE:

query.setParameter(first_name, "%" + searchForm.getFirstName() + "%");

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I want to customize "first_name in Where clause. Can I put ? instead of first_name and setString?

Comment: @oldmidas No. You cannot parameterize the first_name property to pass value at run time.